# unlocked phone can be used for all compatible phone service providers?

Tags: applications, settings, networking, hardware, location-services

There is an Android phone ad like this:

*Due to USA carrier VoLTE restrictions, this phone is only certified to work on T-Mobile and T-Mobile MNVOs(Mint Mobile, Google Fi, etc.) It however is unlocked and will work on any carrier outside the USA. Inside the USA, T-Mobile and T-Mobile MNVOs only.*

I am confused. The phone is unlocked. So it should work for AT&T because T-Mobile and AT&T are both use GSM. And the phone may also work on Verizon if it supports CDMA.  Am I right?  How is the phone restricted to only work on the T-Mobile network?

**EDIT:**

The phone's spec says it will support almost all networks in the world. From a hardware point of view, this unlocked phone can be used for any phone provider in the US?

[image]

Comment: Might help if you could mention the device model to check the spec. While I don't really know what "USA carrier VoLTE restrictions" really are, I think this is about [LTE frequency bands in the USA](https://www.phonearena.com/news/Cheat-sheet-which-4G-LTE-bands-do-AT-T-Verizon-T-Mobile-and-Sprint-use-in-the-USA_id77933) and the fact that not all devices supporting all LTE bands.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of which bands and network frequencies your device supports, the carriers (in the US especially) are notorious for only enabling VoLTE and VoWiFi calling on devices that have been certified by them.

The phone will work with AT&T's 3G and 2G networks if the bands are compatible with them. However, for 4G, the operator is not going to enable VoLTE services since the device is not certified by them. VoLTE provisioning is entirely operator-dependent even if the device hardware supports it.

You can follow the list of AT&T's supported devices below. Only these devices will be able to use VoLTE services once they shut down 3G services (early 2022).

https://www.att.com/idpassets/images/support/wireless/Devices-Working-on-ATT-Network.pdf

**Edit:** The same is for 5G services as well. They'll only enable VoNR for devices that are certified by them.